# Different values for MiddleOfPoints calculation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, trigonometry

I want to calculate the middle of several Geo-Points (speicified by longitude, latitude)
in ObjC

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)middleOfPoints:(NSOrderedSet *)points
{
    int i = 0; i = points.count;
    double x,y,z = 0;

    for (BuildingPoint *point in points) 
    {
        // Iterate through Set
        x += cos(point.latitude.doubleValue*(M_PI/180)) * cos(point.longitude.doubleValue*(M_PI/180));
        y += cos(point.latitude.doubleValue*(M_PI/180)) * sin(point.longitude.doubleValue*(M_PI/180)); 
        z += sin(point.latitude.doubleValue*(M_PI/180)); 
    }

    x = x/i;
    y = y/i;
    z = z/i;

    double longitude = 180/M_PI * atan2(y,x);
    double t = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    double latitude = 180/M_PI * atan2(z,t);

    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
}
```

But for some reason I get different values when I call the method 5 times with the same input set. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check my answer? If it helped, don't forget to "accept" it by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.

Answer (score 0):

```
double x,y,z = 0;
```

initializes only `z` to zero, but `x` and `y` have undefined (random) values. Change it to

```
double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
```